# Infinitesimal momentum element

Tags: statistical-mechanics, momentum

I understand that $d^3x$ is an infinitesimal volume element. But how do I physically make sense of $d^3p$, the momentum element?

Comment: Yes, you can think of $d^3x d^3p$ as a 6-dimensional volume element just with different units  [Length^3 Momentum^3]. Physically you can think of it as the set of particles which have momenta inside a 3D cube of length $dp$ around a fixed vector $\vec{P} $, i.e. $p_i\in [P_i-\frac{dp}{2},P_i+\frac{dp}{2}]$ for $i\in{x,y,z}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, Of course, You can't visualize the Six-dimensional phase space living in the $3$-D. But it's always useful to take examples of lower dimensions. For particles in one dimension, The phase space is $2$-D and can be drawn. In this case, The phase space volume
$$\Delta  V=\Delta q\Delta p$$
which is just the area of the square shown below.

[image]

You can think of doing the same thing in higher dimensions.